# How to detect line breaks in TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

In my Android App I've created 8 TextViews stacked on top of each other. Now I want to load in some plain text into those TextView-Lines. At the moment my Strings have a ";" as delimiter to indicate a line break, however it would be much more convenient if I would detect a linebreak automatically instead of using the hardcoded semicolon approach.

This is my String at the moment:

```
myString = "" +
"This seems to be some sort of spaceship,;" +
"the designs on the walls appear to be of;" +
"earth origin. It looks very clean here.;"
```

And in my other class I load in this string into the 8 TextViews, which I've loaded into an ArrayList, using the ";" as a delimiter.

```
public fun fillLines(myString: String) {
    // How To Make Line Breaks Automatic??

    for(i: Int in str until myString.split(";").size) {
        if(i > textViewArray.size - 1) {
            break
        }
        textViewArray[i].text = myString.split(";")[i]
        textViewArray[i].alpha = 1.0f
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can get the same result as shown above but without hardcoding the delimiter as ";" but instead somehow automatically detect the line break which would occur inside the TextView and then use this as a delimiter to advance through all 8 TextView "Lines".

The reason I need 8 TextViews Stacked On top of each other as individual "text lines" is because of an animation technique I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line-breaking gets fairly complicated, so my recommendation would be that you allow a `TextView` to perform the measuring and layout to determine the line breaks. You could have an invisible `TextView` with the same style as your other views, and attach it to the layout so that it has the same width as your individual `TextView` instances. From there, add a layout change listener, and you can then retrieve the individual lines from the `TextView` `Layout`:

```
myTextView.text = // your text string here
myTextView.addOnLayoutChangeListener { view, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
    (view as? TextView)?.layout?.let { layout ->
        // Here you'll have the individual broken lines:
        val lines = (0 until layout.lineCount).map {
            layout.text.subSequence(layout.getLineStart(it), layout.getLineVisibleEnd(it)
        }
    }
}
```

That said, this comes with the caveat that you'll lose out on hyphenation provided by the `TextView`, so you may wish to disable hyphenation entirely in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill text view with html. Below example.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      tvDocument.setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
 } else {
      tvDocument.setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData));
 }
```

If your delimiter ; it is possible call method `replaceAll(";", "<br>");`

Comment: See my Answer below, my question was how to do this without the semicolon delimiter, the line breaks need to happen automatically..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working now:

First you must add these properties for the textviews:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="none"
```

Then you can do this:

```
public fun fillStorylines() {
    val linecap = 46
    var finalLine: String
    var restChars = ""
    val index = 9999
    val text1: String = "" +
            "This seems to be some sort of spaceship, " +
            "the designs on the walls appear to be of " +
            "earth origin. It looks very clean here. "
    for(j: Int in 0..index) {
        try {
            finalLine = ""
            val lines: List<String> = (restChars + text1.chunked(linecap)[j]).split(" ")
            for (i: Int in 0 until lines.size - 1) {
                finalLine += lines[i] + " "
            }
            textViewArray[j].text = finalLine
            textViewArray[j].alpha = 1.0f
            restChars = lines[lines.size - 1]
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows a more elegant way to solve this please go ahead, your feedback is appreciated :)